# Joomla: How to change menu width

Tags: joomla2.5

I am newby in Joomla programming, so I have a question, how I can to change standard menu modules width, because my menu items don't fit in 960px (standart width), or I want to add something like dropdown in which I can hide all items which are not fited in menu width...

[Here is the screenshoot of my menu!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWM1g.jpg)

**UPDATE 1** here is the link to my site - http://test.consulting.lv/

Comment: If you you don't want your question closed provide some more details, some css and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @WooDzu which of css files exectly you want? I can provide you link to this site to examine it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use firebug (mozzila add-in) to check menu and try different versions (for example try reducing distance between items or changing the font size). 
At the end put/update css code that you made in your template css folder - usually: public_html/template/your_template/css/default.css or smth like this.
Then be careful with your template updates, if you have any.
Hope this helps.